# Height of a random forest decison tree increasing till 25 and the test accuracy also increases

Tags: python, random-forest, cross-validation, xgboost, test-data

I have a dataset of [~16k] and am doing binary classsfication [0/1].When i am doing hyperparameter grid search in random forest my train and test accuracy increase as increase the depth[optimum is coming out to be 25].I am getting a test accuracy of as high as 97% and no there is no data leakage as there are three sets [train,test,and valid].My data has ~10 features.Is this fine since usually i have seen trees have 10 depth at max.

Answer (score 0):

This is **extremely** dependent on the dataset at hand. For such a small dataset tree depth of 25 is indeed on the high side and I would say *somewhat unusual*. But it is *not impossible*. What it can depend on:

- relation between features and the target
- categorical vs numerical features
- imbalance of 0 vs 1 target
- your code implementation (bugs, data leakage, other parameters)

If I were you i would look deeper to understand why such a deep tree is required. For example, you can start by identifying while feature gets the most splits: extract from the best model feature importances with type `split` and get the top-5 features. Look how do those correlate with the target.